# Disable filetype-specific `[`/`]` bindings like `[[` and `[m`

Tags: key-bindings

The default `vim` filetype commands create new bindings beginning with `[` and `]`. Is there a way to prevent them from doing so or control which bindings are created?

I like using `[` and `]` to scroll up and down by half pages, by analogy with `{` and `}` for paragraph navigation.

```
nnoremap ] <c-d>
vnoremap ] <c-d>
xnoremap ] <c-d>

nnoremap [ <c-u>
vnoremap [ <c-u>
xnoremap [ <c-u>
```

It works well for the `text` filetype, but programming language filetypes typically have bindings beginning with `[` and `]`, for instance for Python files there are many structural navigation commands that I tend not to use:

```
...
n  [M          *@:call <SNR>25_Python_jump('n', '\v\S\n*(^(\s*\n*)*(class|def|async def)|^\S)', 'Wb', 0, v:count1)<CR>
n  [m          *@:call <SNR>25_Python_jump('n', '\v^\s*(class|def|async def)>', 'Wb', v:count1)<CR>
n  []          *@:call <SNR>25_Python_jump('n', '\v\S.*\n+(def|class)', 'Wb', 0, v:count1)<CR>
n  [[          *@:call <SNR>25_Python_jump('n', '\v^(class|def|async def)>', 'Wb', v:count1)<CR>
...
n  ]M          *@:call <SNR>25_Python_jump('n', '\v\S\n*(%$|^(\s*\n*)*(class|def|async def)|^\S)', 'W', 0, v:count1)<CR>
n  ]m          *@:call <SNR>25_Python_jump('n', '\v%$|^\s*(class|def|async def)>', 'W', v:count1)<CR>
n  ][          *@:call <SNR>25_Python_jump('n', '\v%$|\S.*\n+(def|class)', 'W', 0, v:count1)<CR>
n  ]]          *@:call <SNR>25_Python_jump('n', '\v%$|^(class|def|async def)>', 'W', v:count1)<CR>
```

The file that defines this is located at

```
/usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/python.vim
```

and does not *appear* to check the value of a "configuration variable" to determine whether it should bind keys.

Is there a creative way to overrule it?

Comment: There are quite a few `[` / `]` mappings. Some of them pretty use full (e.g. `]p` and `[I`). Have you thought about a different set of keys? Maybe `<up>` / `<down>` or just use `<c-u>` & `<c-d>`. Personally, I bind `<d-j>` & `<d-k>`, but that is MacVim specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unmap these within a file called `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` or `$HOME/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/python.vim` on windows, etc. containing:

```
silent! nunmap <buffer> ]]
silent! nunmap <buffer> [[
silent! nunmap <buffer> ][
silent! nunmap <buffer> []
" and so on ...
```

vim executes scripts of the form `after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` *after* `ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` so you cna provide arbitrary overrides to the defaults.

Alternatively, you can use autocmds within your vimrc as follows:

```
function! PythonUnmaps()
    silent! nunmap <buffer> ]]
    silent! nunmap <buffer> [[
    silent! nunmap <buffer> ][
    silent! nunmap <buffer> []
    " and so on...
endfunction
augroup my_python_overrides
    au!
    autocmd FileType python call PythonUnmaps()
augroup END
```

Both of these approaches are general, you can replace python with whichever filetype you want to alter the settings for.

Comment: Is there a way to override it from within the `.vimrc` itself?

Comment: edited that into the answer

Answer (score 2):

According to the help [:h no_mail_maps](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#no_mail_maps) and [:h no_plugin_maps](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#no_plugin_maps), it should be possible to prevent the creation of a filetype specific mapping by setting the variable:

```
:let g:no_<filetype>_maps = 1`
```

in your .vimrc, with `<filetype>` being replaced by `python` in your case. Unfortunately, the [official python filetype plugin](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim) does not support this guard yet.

However, the upstream [python Vim filetype repository](https://github.com/tpict/vim-ftplugin-python) does already support that as of commit [db75a4614ffef770](https://github.com/tpict/vim-ftplugin-python/commit/db75a4614ffef7700620498f46166b9730ecde8f)

So you could simply clone that plugin locally and use that, until the maintainer has sent update runtime files to Bram for inclusion with Vim (and Bram has committed it to the Vim repository).